# How to create a scope for a sniper

Tags: opengl

I am developing a first-person shooter/strategy game using the Lightweight Java Game Library, which has support for OpenGL. I would like to create a sniper which I need to magnify the screen and project an image onto the back of the scope.
I have tried using gluPerspective() for zooming in and out, but it just makes the screen go black.
I am thinking about using glReadPixels for grabbing pixel data from the zoomed in image, but I'm not sure what to put in field 'data'. [explanation of glreadpixels here](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) I'm also not sure how to get the data from glReadPixels and put it back onto the back of the scope.

EDIT: I'm not doing full screen zooming, I'm showing the image on the back of the scope.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is the zoomed image [full screen](http://press2reset.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Borderlands2Screen1.jpg)? Or is it shown on the [back of the scope](http://i1152.photobucket.com/albums/p498/SwashbucklerLimey/Borderlands%202/LegendaryfromPiratechest2_zps6036073e.jpg) like in Borderlands 2?

Comment: It is shown on the back of the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great tutorial (c++) on how to create a camera for opengl on:

http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/glCamera3.html

It has functionality for zooming in and out. I've used it for my implementation in LWJGL.

Comment: I assumed you meant fullscreen zooming.

Comment: The data field should be a ByteBuffer pixel = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3 * number of pixels);

But glReadPixels is a quite heavy instruction.

Comment: "This demo requires OpenGL 1.3 or higher support." - that isn't really welcoming, considering we're at 4.3 now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render the scope full-screen, just change the projection accordingly, and add the crosshair onto the picture.

If you want to render the world in the scope when the gun is being held down, you have to do the same, but render to texture this time, and then project this texture on the gun's scope.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create A Framebuffer **x**
2. Draw the world except the player on it
3. Copy the Framebuffer into another buffer **y**
4. Draw the player on framebuffer **y**
5. Convert **x** to a texture then shade it on the scope in **y**